# How to implement the addition of an item in array when you click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

help me please implement the addition a clicked item in to container 
I have angular app with draglar plugin 
and all is great but now need make mobile version

-instead of dragging an item it is necessary to add it on click 

I'm stuck on 86 line

here is an example http://bit.ly/1MKq4IG  <==  plnkr

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Jquery UI Touch Punch.
IT will let you use drag&drop features in mobile device, without changing you code.

```
http://touchpunch.furf.com/
```

All you have to is to add this script to your page

Comment: I didnt set -1,
only +1, but i know this way. and realy need make it on click

Comment: You set -1... I would look for other answer. Why you need onclick?

Comment: I cant even set it http://joxi.ru/zANp9BxhQDVwm9 ..
onclick need for mobile version